# Two views in horizontal chain, when one is View.GONE, the other should be centered in parent

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have two views next to each other in a constraintLayout horizontal chain.

However, when one of the views is View.GONE (programmatically set), I want the other view to be centered within its parent. I've tried horizontal chaining but it doesn't seem to work.

i.e. I want to go from this:
[image]

to this:
[image]

However, when I set button 2 to View.GONE, button 1 stays in the same position, slightly skewed to the left, as if button 2 was View.INVISIBLE rather than View.GONE.

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/btn_2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/btn_1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/btn_2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/btn_4"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had a constraintLayout Group that referenced the two buttons that was interfering with the chaining. Once I removed the Group, everything worked as expected.